# if this input has value doesn't work in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this simple code to filter through a search form with many text inputs and see if they have a value and then add a class.
Works perfectly in Chrome, safari and Firefox but not in IE9.

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== '') {
    $(this).addClass('used');
  }
});
```

Please advice, thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Change to each but doesn't solve the issue... Here it is with the event that triggers the function...

```
   $(document).on('event-ajax-form-is-loaded', function() {
      $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $(this).addClass('used');
        }
      });
   });
```

Comment: You didn't explain what actually happens on IE9 that isn't supposed to. Do they all end up with the class `used`? Do none? What's `.val()` returning?

Comment: That's not really what you use `.filter()` for…

Comment: That's not the correct use of ```filter()```.

Comment: Also, what they said -- I'd use `.each()` rather than `.filter()`.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the issue, show some markup doesn't work.  Not all of it -- but enough that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @sphanley, see it live here if you're on IE... It breaks the ajax calls...http://dev.wleiprocoves.com/produits

Comment: Well, according to [this page](http://jquery.com/browser-support/), all of jQuery 2.x is supported for IE9+.

Comment: That's really not a helpful response -- I'm not on Internet Explorer 9, nor do I want to manually debug your web page. Since you presumably do know what isn't working right, feel free to let us know so we can try to help you.

Comment: It probably isn't working because you're **incorrectly** using `.filter()`, as everyone has already said. The `.filter()` function is expecting a return and you aren't providing one.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `(function($) {` ?  What you have does not look functional.

Comment: You right about filter, It was part of a longer function but anyway even with each it doesn't seem to work... I am using browserstack to debug this in IE9 and it is sometimes a little finnicky so any leads would be great!...

Comment: @jfriend00, mark up typos... was missing the closing tags with jquery for wordpress and no conflict

Comment: Put a breakpoint or `console.log()` statements in your `.on()` handler and see if it is even getting called.  You need some rudimentary debugging here to troubleshoot your own issue.  We can't do that without running code to look at.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have other things triggered by the .on handler that works fine... I did check the console log and it is getting called.

Comment: Nothing else we can suggest then because there's nothing wrong with your latest iteration of the code.  It is some interaction with other code or with your HTML, neither of which we can see.

Answer (score 1):

From the limited information you shared, this is how you should be doing this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() !== '';
}).addClass('used');
```

**.filter()** is supposed to reduce a set of matched elements so its filter function should always *return* a bool instead of manipulating the DOM.

**Edit:** Based on your updated code snippet and the page link you shared in the comments, if you are using jQuery in WordPress, then its always safer to wrap the code like so:

```
(function($) {
    /* jQuery Code using $ object */
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks... I did, but still not working. Also try with filter and return and it doesn't work

Comment: Is your event being fired? It might be that the problem lies there instead.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`In `JS` you can check the element value by getting their tag name

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++){
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value == "")
    {
        alert("The value of textbox at " + i + " is empty");
    }
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/67egu/)

Or like what other people suggest, use a `.each` in `JQuery`

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(i){

if ($(this).val() == "") {
    alert("The value of textbox at " + i + " is empty");
  }

});
```

[anohter Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/67egu/1/)

If you insist to use `filter` and here you go

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter(function() 
     {  return $( this ).val() != "";  }).addClass("used");
```

[Last Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/67egu/2/)

and [jquery filter reference](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: And, why would this solve the OP's issue?  This code also doesn't do the same thing as the OP's because they are only processing text input fields.